# TSQL: How to get unique rownumbers without sorting

Tags: t-sql, row-number

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, MyColumn NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyTable (Id, MyColumn)
VALUES (NEWID(), N'1')
      ,(NEWID(), N'1234')
      ,(NEWID(), N'12')
      ,(NEWID(), N'123')

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MyColumn) as rownumber,
    MyColumn
FROM @MyTable
```

With the defined select query I get a proper rownumber **but** my insert order is gone as well.

It returns:

```
rownumber   MyColumn
----------- ---------
1           1
2           12
3           123
4           1234
```

I understand why it sorts (the `OVER(ORDER BY ...)` is required) but that's not what I want.

How can I get the the rownumber **without** sorting the result?

Comment: A row number does not make semantically sense without an ordering  specifying what the row number means. What are you trying to achieve more specifically?

Comment: Rows have no set order.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use this solution if you realy want use rn and also delete data betwen insert and select statement... If there isnt delete or some other logic between , you could select only identity_column, then you dont need RN, just order by id_identity, then you reach data ordered by insert ...

```
 DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, MyColumn NVARCHAR(50), id_identity int identity)
        INSERT INTO @MyTable (Id, MyColumn)
        VALUES (NEWID(), N'1')
              ,(NEWID(), N'1234')
              ,(NEWID(), N'12')
              ,(NEWID(), N'123')
/*Some logic here*/        

        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id_identity) as rownumber,
            MyColumn
        FROM @MyTable
```

Comment: Would that not just be the same as select id_identity

Comment: As i say, only if between not be implemented some logic, For example delete some values, then identity sould be 1,3,4.. You know, but i suppose , he want 1,2,3...

Comment: In my example I used a temp table. But what if the table already exists?

Comment: put before creatiing temp following statement:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTmpName') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #yourTmpName

Comment: @Matej I meant to say. I have an existing table. I am not allowed to change this table structure.

Comment: Understood. But you can declare another table variable table2 for example with identity property , insert data from your table, that you couldnt change like INSERT INTO table2(Id,Mycolumn) SELECT Id,Mycolumn FROM myoldtable and in select use same logic as in example code. Insert without order, in sql is ordered by source order... Like  SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id_identity) as rownumber,
            MyColumn
        FROM table2. This option is not good(performance), but if you couldnt change your table, its only option.